# Finding Prime Numbers which are factors

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to return the factors of a number which are prime numbers in this code. For example, if someone enters in `n = 100`, they'll get back 2 and 5. I believe I have the first part correct in checking for the factors, but somehow I'm not sure what I'm missing in the second part of checking for prime numbers.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks.

```
l = []

def factor(n):

    print 'These are the factors:'
    for num in range(2,n):
        if n%num == 0: #checks that it is a factor
            print num #These are the factors
            l.append(num)    

    for i in l: 
        if i%2 == 0 and i > 2: #checks for even numbers
            l.remove(i)

        else:
            for x in range(3,i,2): #checks for odd numbers
                if i%x == 0:
                    l.remove(i)


    print l
```

Comment: I've tried it with 100 and it returned [2,5,20,50]. Why aren't 20 and 50 removed?

I also tried it with 90 and I get an error "list.remove(x): x not in list.

I'm not sure I fully understand why. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are removing from the list as you are looping through it.  Behind the scenes you are basically doing a `for` loop with an `i` counter.  So when you are on `index = 1` (the value is 4 in this case), you remove it and increment the index.  As a result, the value `5` gets moved into the location where `4` was before and the index is incremented.  This causes the value `5` to never be checked.  The same holds true for your values of `20` and `50`.  They are never being checked so they wouldn't be removed.

Comment: Thanks for that. That does make sense given that I have a for loop implemented. Any ideas on how else I could implement this?

Comment: So I think the way I would do it is by looping over the last and simply picking out what you want and building a new list. There's probably a python way of doing it with a lambda function but that's a bit more advanced.